# High Beams work, Low beams don't, But . .

Tags: headlight, lincoln

So I have a 1986 Lincoln Continental. The issue is that for a while my low beams worked. Then one of my low beams went out, about a week later my other low beam stopped working.

Now here is the kicker, the High beams work, and when the High beams are on - so do the low beams.

I know this question has been asked a few times, but since my vehicle is of such age I cannot find good, layman documentation. I come from owning a 2001 Pontiac so this is all very foreign to me. If someone could help me figure out this issue that'd be awesome. I don't want to spend money on headlights just to have that not be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headlights are a four headlight system. These are sealed beam headlights. Two of the bulbs are strictly for high-beam use (inside bulbs). Two of the headlights function for both hi/low beams (outside bulbs).

In each of the hi/low bulbs, there are two separate filaments which work for either of the modes.

What is going on with your headlights is the two low-beam filaments have failed. The two hi-beam filaments are still working.

Get new bulbs for the two outside positions and you should be golden.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around your answer (not debating though) - you are saying that this system has hi/low filaments in both the hi/low bulbs? Meaning there are 4 bulbs and 8 filaments in total?

Comment: No, four bulbs *six* filaments, two each in the outside bulbs.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Submitted an edit to your phrasing to make it more clear and changed some of the ambiguous wordings.

Comment: Thank you so much, I ended up trying this anyway and they work! I certainly understand what you mean, since the bulbs are sealed when the high beams are on it uses both lights but with different filaments. Taking them out was an adventure but overall it was a fun process, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @MorganB. - You're welcome and come back anytime. We have *all kinds of answers* for you ;-)