# 2007 CTS low beam headlights don't work, but high beams do work

Tags: electrical, headlight, cts

How can I get started on fixing this?

Comment: 2007 CTS low beam headlight dot work highbeam do

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're talking about? It's not making sense. Also, what trouble shooting have you done to try and fix your issue? Have you replaced bulbs? Tested/replaced relays? Tested/replace fuses? Tested the high beam mechanism?

Comment: It is fine to post a minimal (e.g., the best you can figure out at the moment) question to get started, but when you do it really helps if you can get back to the question to respond to comments. People here are friendly and helpful and you'll probably find a comment asking for clarification (or an answer) within an hour or two.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of a dual-beam bulb. Note that it has 2 filaments as labelled:

[image]

You need to check if one of the filaments has fried. If the filament isokay for both high and low beam then you will need to replace your relay

Here is image of the fuse/relay block under the hood:
[image]

Check for the low beam as highlighted below:
[image]

1. Test the relay (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ire7vyDqelg)
2. Order the relay if not good
3. Replace the relay

Answer (score 0):

It is common for low beams to get used more than the highs, so it might be as simple as checking and changing the bulbs. Failing that, start by checking the fuse(es). If neither of those moves solve the problem, here are a few questions and answers that will probably help if you get it sorted out:

- [Low beam headlights don't work, High beam headlights do](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/low-beam-headlights-dont-work-high-beam-headlights-do?rq=1)
- [High Beams work, Low beams don't, But…](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18564/high-beams-work-low-beams-dont-but?rq=1)

Also, take a look at the Related links on the right, there is often good information there.